RMarkDown-No se como se anade el resultado del codigo al documento
Estoy tratando de que el codigo en el chunk me corra y lo integre al documento HTLM.  Pero cuendo presiono knit no me lo corre.
EL codigo que use fue
{r echo=FALSE}
library(magrittr)

table(Visitas_San_Marcos$Year,Visitas_San_Marcos$Genero)

y me sale una pantalla que dice Render en la cual pone:
 |.....................                               |  40% [setup]          

processing file: IglesiaEvangelicaLuteranaSanMarcos.Rmd
                                                                                                            

Quitting from lines  at lines 47-51 [unnamed-chunk-1] (IglesiaEvangelicaLuteranaSanMarcos.Rmd)
Error:
! object 'Visitas_San_Marcos' not found
Backtrace:
 1. base::table(Visitas_San_Marcos$Year, Visitas_San_Marcos$Genero)
Execution halted


El error significa que el objeto o dataframe que estas usando Visitas_San_Marcos no se encuentra en el enviroment de R, en otras palabras, no tienes cargada la data. Por tanto antes de correr la función table(), tienes que importar la data en to rmarkdown file.

Gracias ya lo vi.  Muy amable!
